# Clear cron job cache in Linux apache

Tags: laravel, apache, amazon-ec2, cron

I'm facing some facing some problems regarding cron job from last day. I want to clear my cron cache. Actually the problem is server do not picking up my latest shell command setup instead it is picking up my very first job that was every minute. Please do let me know how my latest cron will run. It must be cache issue I think. I also restart my apache running on instance ec2 but it didn't solved my problem.
Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as cron cache?   You are talking about jobs.  Presumably queues, and you need to restart your queue worker?

Comment: I'm talking about cron job. Please take a look at below command in parenthesis .
( * */6 * * *  root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /home/ec2-user/cron_file.log 2>&1 )
I want to run cron job by every 6 hours but unfortunately it is running on every minute.

Comment: Cron jobs can be run per user so maybe you initially created the cronjob under a different user.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the laravel scheduler every minute and then create a task in the kernel.php that runs according to the schedule frequency you define.

Don't create an additional call to schedule:run expecting that this will be the only invocation.

Doing it in the kernel.php means that your application behaviour is designed in code and is not dependent on task specific cron jobs setup on your server.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

In your case, you would schedule the activity and then add `->everySixHours();` to the end of the schedule command.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for your response. My problem is when I update cron job command then it is not working. Very first one is working that even does not exists.

Comment: My first command was (* * * * *) and my latest command is (* */6 * * *). My latest command is not working. I think its  cache issue

Comment: Issue has been resolved. The issue was when you modify the main cron file and restart apache server then it create a previous copy of cron file. That's why it was hitting every minute and after 6 hours both.